# Error installing Visual Studio Multi device Applications after update

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have recently updated Visual Studio 2013 to version 4 and then I have tried to update Apache Cordova Multi Device Tools to the new version but I get an error saying its blocked and I have to uninstall the older version.

I clicked the link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=518308&clcid=0x409 and tried to follow the instructions but it says in the CMD prompt that the file dosn't exist.  I have checked and the Hybrid Apps CPT2.0 is not in my Programs and Features list so it's deleted ok and there are no registry keys I can find either...

So now I have a Visual Studio install that won't allow me to build MultiDevice Apps and a customer that is not understanding my issue.  Anyone Please...

Cliff.

Comment: Run all the four commands one by one mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133, one will succeed and others will report file does not exist. After running all the 4 commands, try installing vs2013mda_0.3.exe. If you still get the error post the log from %temp%

Comment: I have done all 4 commands and they all give the same file does not exist error. I searched the whole PC for the vs2013mda file as some forums say the GUID's are different on each PC but again no luck.  Where is the log file you suggest?

Comment: IS it worth unistalling VS and doing a fresh install or will I face the same issue as the new install will see that same failure when installing the Cordova package.

Comment: Uninstalling the VS will not help. can you send the install log from %temp% when you try to install CTP3.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675

Comment: The install log will be named something like dd_mda_tools_nnnnnnn.log.  You can email vscordovatools@microsoft.com directly for assistance with this.

Comment: Thanks log file sent over so hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your reading this and struggling for an answer I managed to resolve the issue with some help from the MSFT team listed in the comments above (All via email) great service from them.

The answer was that I manually went through my Package Cache folder looking for anything mentioning the MultiDeviceHybridApp and found there was a package in this location:

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{19AD9AD6-4205-4C29-A4ED-9C62483544D4}v12.0\packages\MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS\MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi

I then using CMD (Admin mode) moved to the right directory and run the following command to uninstall the package:

MSIEXEC /X MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi

The uninstaller then runs takes a few minutes and I could then install the CTP3 package without issue.

Hope it helps you and good luck with building your app.

Cliff.

Comment: The commands listed on the MS site were not working for me.. every one of them came back with errors (invalid command). Your solution here may be the one... I've been struggling with this for 3 days. rant... and I've been up for 36 hours trying to make a deadline.

Comment: This works also when installing the VS2013 Update 5 and it complains about old Cordova tools. UUID is different though: {FE8899F5-CA4F-4D89-9D00-5BB97C74A383}v12.0

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in the KB article but I still had the same error message when trying to install CTP3 of the Cordova tools. I even tried reinstalling Visual Studio and multiple reboots, but the problem persisted.

I was able to resolve the issue by running the original CTP2 installer from the command line using the /uninstall and /force options. I assume this deleted whatever registry keys or other artifacts were blocking the CTP3 install.

```
> vs2013mda_0.2.exe /uninstall /force
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `CTP2` install but the command:

```
vs2013mda_0.3.exe /uninstall /force
```

Worked and got me the ability to install `vs2013mda_0.3.1.exe`.

I also rebooted.. but I probably didn't need to.