# VS2013 Update 5 blocked due to old version of Multi-Device Hybrid Apps

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I thought I should post this here to help anybody else encountering this problem when installing the new Update 5 for VS2013.

I spent about 3 days now trying to install Update 5 for Visual Studio 2013 with the installer saying the update is blocked due to there being a version of Multi-Device Development for Hybrid Apps (MDD) already present on the machine.

I had removed the CTP of MDD but obviously something was still lurking on the machine that made the installer think that it was still there. I checked out a bunch of threads like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514447/error-installing-visual-studio-multi-device-applications-after-update) relating to the problem in earlier Updates of VS2013 and also [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3014133) article on Microsoft Support. I found no trace of the referenced files in Package Cache.

Below is the fix I found.

Comment: This little registry touch helped me as un-blocker after trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913475/error-when-installing-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp3-0-in-visual-st) and some manual registry deletes of keys referring to "Multi-Device Hybrid Apps". Consider splitting your description into question/answer parts so that the answer can be voted on and marked as accepted

Comment: Glad it worked for you too xmojmr. I took your suggestion and split it into two parts for problem and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got round this issue by taking a long shot and searching in the Registry using RegEdit for the phrase "Multi-Device" in any reg key associated with Visual Studio 12. I found in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\JavaScriptLanguageService

An entry called ReferenceGroups_MDD.

What I actually did was remove the whole thing from JavascriptLanguageService down but I reckon you could just remove that one single key. Voila! Update 5 installed.

I hope this is of some use to others who also get stuck with this.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. I was stuck with this the past couple of days.

Comment: I reformatted my computer and trying to install VS2013.5 for the first time.  I have no VisualStudio folder in the registery, but still getting the Setup error message.  ugh!